# Toggle view of folder pane in Thunderbird

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, thunderbird

I'm new to *Thunderbird* and need to toggle the folder pane view with a hotkey. The sequence that works now is: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and repeat to close it.

I'm very grateful for any help.
I'm using Thunderbird 60.2.1 on Win 7 Pro 32bit.

Comment: I have found out that Durando Keyconfig and Menu Wizard don't work with my version 60.2.1  I'm not sure if Autohotkey will do more than two keys deep? Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [thunderbird support page](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts#w_customize-or-disable-keyboard-shortcuts) You need some extension to redefine keyboard shortcuts.

For example [Dorando Keyconfig](https://addons.thunderbird.net/thunderbird/addon/dorando-keyconfig/)

Add new key, name it, check as `global`, and add following code:

```
goDoCommand('cmd_toggleFolderPane');
```

and set a keyboard shortcut to new key.

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Comment: thx see above note.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to refer to Worthwelle reply.

Comment: @PaulSoundman look at my edit. checked on 60.2.1 on Linux.

Comment: Hi Tomasz. Not sure if I'm doing the answering right but thanks for the command line. The extension "Dorando" apparently won't work with my version of TB (60.2.1)